# Access Node in html.tpl.php in Drupal 7

Tags: theming, nodes, users

I am trying to access the current $node variables in the html.tpl.php within Drupal 7. The problem is that I am running a Analytics software in the backend for which I've to record each page's analytics from html.tpl.php.

If there's a normal page, I have to record generic attributes but if it's a node, I need the following things in the `html.tpl.php`:-

- Title of the Content (Node)
- Content Type of the Content

I can do this in `node.tpl.php` through `$node->type;`, but unfortunately I need it in html.tpl.php.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the current menu object with [`menu_get_object()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7). From there you can determine if that object is a node or not. Since it defaults to "node" it will be empty if you're not on a node page and will have all the normal node object stuff available if you are.

```
$node = menu_get_object()
```

Comment: That's great! Let me try that. I'll post any problems here. Thanks.